# Extjs wrapping multiple combo boxes in a container

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I have a number of combo boxes in a fluid layout that appear alongside each other

I would like the combo boxes to wrap underneath if there is insufficient space to display them alongside each other.

Here is a fiddle of what i have so far -  https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1mn1

The items align correctly in a container with layout hbox but no wrapping overflowing seems to be occurring.

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
title: 'Combo boxes',
width: '100%',
layout: 'vbox',
items: [{
    xtype: 'container',
    layout: 'hbox',
    items: [{                    
        xtype:'combo',
        store: states,
        displayField: 'name',
        valueField: 'abbr'            
    },
    {                    
        xtype:'combo',
        store: states,
        displayField: 'name',
        valueField: 'abbr'            
    },
    {                    
        xtype:'combo',
        store: states,
        displayField: 'name',
        valueField: 'abbr'            
    },
    {                    
        xtype:'combo',
        store: states,
        displayField: 'name',
        valueField: 'abbr'            
    }]
}],        
renderTo: Ext.getBody()
```

});

How can i get the combo boxes to wrap as required ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    // The data store containing the list of states
var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
    data: [{
            "abbr": "AL",
            "name": "Alabama"
        }, {
            "abbr": "AK",
            "name": "Alaska"
        }, {
            "abbr": "AZ",
            "name": "Arizona"
        }
        //...
    ]
});
Ext.create({
    xtype: 'viewport',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [
        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            title: 'Combo boxes',
            style: 'display: flex;',
            defaults: {
                style: 'float:left;'
            },
            items: [{
                xtype: 'combo',
                store: states,
                displayField: 'name',
                valueField: 'abbr'
            }, {
                xtype: 'combo',
                store: states,
                displayField: 'name',
                valueField: 'abbr'
            }, {
                xtype: 'combo',
                store: states,
                displayField: 'name',
                valueField: 'abbr'
            }, {
                xtype: 'combo',
                store: states,
                displayField: 'name',
                valueField: 'abbr'
            }]
        })
    ]
});
```

[Here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1mn9) is a working fiddle.

A style is applied to the panel, then every component gets the `style:'float:left;'` by the panel's defaults property, that sets to every item the properties in the object.

The panel will always put the combos wrapped if the width changes, I updated the fiddle to show you that you can resize it without problems.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can this solution work if the browser window is resized ? I'm testing in Chrome 49

Comment: @grimmus answer updated, try to resize the view and you'll se that combos will wrap instantly